# How do I change the organizer dropdown so that only MARK'd sections are shown? SWIFT - XCODE

Tags: xcode

[image: Right now all the functions are shown and it's a bit annoying.]

I would like all of the functions to be hidden, and only my "MARK" items to be shown.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if what you want is possible, but if you put a dash in front of section name (e.g. `MARK: - Top 3 buttons` you will get nice separators

Comment: Sidenote, the latest versions of Xcode also creates a more hierarchical dropdown view, which might be helpful for you

Comment: Thanks, I assume you guys are referring to Xcode 13.5 and after? Since I have 13.4